# MkrWan freezes after short power outage

Tags: power

My MkrWan running on 5v 3A external adapter without battery. When short time(15-20 second) power outage happens Mkrwan still seems running. I think it consumes power on capacitors on adapter but voltage value drops. When electric comes back, it doesnt work anymore. Why it doesnt reset itself ?
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: "Mkrwan still seems running" how do you see this? "When electric comes back, it doesnt work anymore" how do you see this?

Comment: Because of the led on it seems on and light does not go out.

Comment: What is the firmware programmed to do? Please edit to show the code.

Comment: a brownout can cause all sorts of unexpected and hard to diagnose issues. Maybe add brownout detection, uses a less buffered PSU, use a bleeder resistor, or a battery backup.

Comment: dandavis as you said it looks like brownout problem(I never heard before you). To solve it, ordered Lipo batteries, I will test and will inform if it solves.

Answer (score 1):

I connected Lipo battery to device. On power outages it supply power to board and brown out problem solved. Thanks a lot

Comment: It is OK to accept your own answer as the solution to the problem.